# Differential Lyapunov equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, linear-control, lyapunov-functions

Given the continuous-time differential Lyapunov equation

$$\mathbf{A}(t)^T\mathbf{P}(t)+\mathbf{P}(t)\mathbf{A}(t)+\dot{\mathbf{P}}(t)=-\mathbf{Q}(t)$$

where $\mathbf{A}(t)$ and $\mathbf{Q}(t)$ are both continuous and bounded, there exists a unique solution $\mathbf{P}(t)$.   In addition, assume that $\mathbf{Q}(t)$ is positive definite and $\mathbf{A}(t)$ is Hurwitz.

Under what additional assumptions can one guarantee that the solution $\mathbf{P}(t)$ is positive definite? Is this even possible? I am not interested in the solution to the equation.

I would greatly appreciate any comments or pointers where I can find more info about this problem. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by Hurwitz when considering time-varying $A(t)$? Note that having all eigenvalues with negative real parts does not imply stability of an LTV.

Comment: Yes, by Hurwitz I mean the matrix $\mathbf{A}(t)$ has constant eigenvalues with negative real parts. With that in mind is there a way to guarantee positive definite $\mathbf{P}(t)$ by putting restrictions on $\mathbf{A}(t)$ or $\mathbf{Q}(t)$? @Arastas

Comment: @Matsz09 Why not focus on the time-invariant case first?

Comment: @ Rodrigo de Azevedo, Thank you for cleaning up the original post. As far as the problem is concerned, if I assume a time-invariant case I get $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{P}+\mathbf{P}\mathbf{A}=-\mathbf{Q}$ which for Hurwitz $\mathbf{A}$ and positive definite $\mathbf{Q}$ always guarantees positive definite solution $\mathbf{P}$. I am not sure how this helps in solving the above?

Comment: @Matsz09 By "time-invariant", I meant that $A$ is constant, though not $P$. You would still have a matrix differential equation.

Comment: Take a look at Antsaklis & Michel.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo, thank you for the reference. By hand I can only do a scalar case, $Q(t)=Q$, and assuming the solution of the form $P(t)=\Phi(t,t_0)P(0)\Phi(t,t_0)^T+\int_{t_0}^t\Phi(t,s)Q\Phi(t,s)^Tds$ which leads to $P(t)=e^{2A(t-t_0)}\big(P(0)+\frac{Q}{2A}\big)-\frac{Q}{2A}$ which at steady state gives solution to time-invariant solution $P=-\frac{Q}{2A}$. Then $A<0$ always guarantees $P>0$.

Comment: @Matsz09 Please include that work on the question itself. The act of writing often clarifies one's thinking.